# Android app is blocked by "Mail would like to: Have offline access"

Tags: google-signin

We are developing an Android app for login gmail and encountered one problem.
We do as the develop guide(https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/start?authuser=1). But the app was blocked by "Mail would like to: Have offline access" in one special device. The screenshot is as below. After clicking "Allow" and the same dialog will pop up again. But the app can login successfully on the other devices.
Could anyone help us?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UVWSo.png)

Answer (score 0):

This special phone's date is wrong. It's 4 days later than today.
After correcting the time, everything goes well.
What a strange root cause!